# Integrative Medicine Tag

Tags: feature-request

I believe an integrative tag should be added.

Integrative medicine takes a different approach and is becoming more popular today 
[[1]](https://stanfordhealthcare.org/medical-clinics/integrative-medicine-center.html)[[2]](https://oshercenter.org/).

Comment: I've got no problem whatsoever with an integrative medicine tag, but homeopathy is recognized by absolutely no one with any science credentials as valid medical treatment (NHS notwithstanding; they apparently caved to political pressure). In fact, I think most integrative medicine doctors would be as dismissive of homeopathy as I am.

Comment: I don't think there's any need to even mention homeopathy in regard to an integrative medicine tag. The less it's acknowledged, the better.

Comment: Probably ([meta-tag:tags]) would be a suitable tag for this question. (I do not have sufficient reputation to edit on meta - which is why I made this suggestion in a comment instead.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just created the tag, so we can end this thread on a positive note. :-) If you have sufficient reputation, you can create tags by asking a question and adding a new tag, **or** by editing an existing question and adding it. I did the latter on a highly-upvoted question that brought up integrative medicine in 2015.